# Альтернатива Advanced Bash Scripting Guide?

Tags: bash

Собственно, есть ли она? (man bash не считается)

**Up:**

[linuxconfig.org/BashScriptingTutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial)

[BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/HOWTO-ru/Bash-Progr-Intro-HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html#toc10)

Кто найдет еще что-нибудь, кидайте в ответы.

Comment: Типа нужен продвинутый учебник/справочник по Bash?

Comment: Не обязательно продвинутый, подойдет любой мануал по написанию скриптов на bash.

Comment: По-английски пойдет?

Comment: Да, подойдет.